# Retrieving rows that have 2 columns matching and 1 different

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is my table called 'datapoints'. I am trying to retrieve instances where there are different instances of 'sensorValue' for the same 'timeOfReading' and 'sensorNumber'.

For example:

```
 sensorNumber sensorValue timeOfReading

      5            5           6
      5            5           6
      5            6           10   <----same time/sensor diff value!
      5            7           10   <----same time/sensor diff value!
```

Should output: sensorNumber:5, timeOfReading: 10 as a result.

[image: datapoints table]

I understand this is a duplicate question, in fact I have one of the links provided below for references - however none of the solutions are working as my query simply never ends.

Below is my SQL code:

```
SELECT table1.sensorNumber, table1.timeOfReading
FROM datapoints table1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM datapoints table2
        WHERE table1.sensorNumber = table2.sensorNumber
        AND table1.timeOfReading = table1.timeOfReading 
        AND table1.sensorValue != table2.sensorValue) > 1
        AND table1.timeOfReading < 20;
```

Notice I have placed a bound for timeOfReading as low as 20. I also tried setting a bound for both table1 and table 2 as well but the query just runs until timeout without displaying results no matter what I put...

The database contains about 700mb of data, so I do not think I can just run this on the entire DB in a reasonable amount of time, I am wondering if this is the culprit?

If so how could I properly limit my query to run a search efficiently? If not what am doing wrong that this is not working?

[Select rows having 2 columns equal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076766/select-rows-having-2-columns-equal-value)

EDIT: 
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query  600.000 sec

When I try to run the query again I get this error unless I restart 
Error Code: 2006. MySQL server has gone away    0.000 sec

Comment: technically I also should add: "AND table1.sensorValue != table2.sensorValue" because I am specifically looking for instances where they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a self-JOIN to match related rows in the same table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.sensorNumber, t1.timeOfReading
FROM datapoints AS t1
JOIN datapoints AS t2 
    ON t1.sensorNumber = t2.sensorNumber
    AND t1.timeOfReading = t2.timeOfReading
    AND t1.sensorValue != t2.sensorValue
WHERE t1.timeOfReading < 20
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/beeb0/1)

To improve performance, make sure you have a composite index on `sensorNumber` and `timeOfReading`:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_sn_tr on datapoints (sensorNumber, timeOfReading);
```

Comment: This one actually ran to completion, but with empty results. Attempting to find those duplicate solutions I will get back to you if it works. It still takes quite a while to run.

Comment: @NutellaAddict : To improve sql performace, you need to explain the statement and check where the problem lies. Also, you need to add indexes for columns used in conditions.

Comment: @NutellaAddict I get a result with your sample data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/beeb0/1

Answer (score 2):

I think you have missed a condition. Add a not condition also to retrieve only instances with different values.

```
SELECT * 
FROM new_table a 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM new_table b 
              WHERE a.num = b.num 
                AND a.timeRead = b.timeRead 
                AND a.value != b.value);
```

Comment: Thanks I just realized that and added in the comment. But the issue remains that the query just does not finish running with or without that additional condition.

Comment: @NutellaAddict Don't add important things in a comment, edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return the sensorNumber and the timeOfReading where there are different values of sensorValue:

```
select sensorNumber, timeOfReading
from tablename
group by sensorNumber, timeOfReading
having count(distinct sensorValue)>1
```

and this will return the actual records:

```
select t.*
from
  tablename t inner join (
    select sensorNumber, timeOfReading
    from tablename
    group by sensorNumber, timeOfReading
    having count(distinct sensorValue)>1
  ) d on t.sensorNumber=d.sensorNumber and t.timeOfReading=d.timeOfReading
```

I would suggest you to add an index on sensorNumber, timeOfReading

```
alter table tablename add index idx_sensor_time (sensorNumber, timeOfReading)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this query

```
select testTable.* from testTable inner join (

SELECT sensorNumber,timeOfReading
FROM testTable
 group by sensorNumber , timeOfReading having Count(distinct sensorValue) > 1) t
 on
 t.sensorNumber = testTable.sensorNumber and t.timeOfReading = testTable.timeOfReading;
```

here is [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b273/10)