# Selecting rows with multiple equal column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write an SQL command that returns me every record, where the `name`, `age` and `city` column has the same value in the same table.

```
id  name  age  city
1   John  22   London
2   John  22   London
3   Nancy 24   Tokyo
```

I've already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076766/select-rows-having-2-columns-equal-value), and it seems it's exactly what I want, but unfortunately when I run the below command the PhpMyAdmin starts loading and doesn't finish it and I get a `"Gateway Timeout error"` so I assume I'm doing something wrong. I'm not an sql wizard so I would really appreciate if somebody could fix my code.

I don't really understand the full code but I think `ta` and `ta2` is a variable that represent my table name, but I'm not familiar with this topic so any help would be useful.

```
SELECT ta.name
      ,ta.age
      ,ta.city

FROM mytablename ta
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM mytable ta2
       WHERE ta.name = ta2.name
       AND ta.age =ta2.age
       AND ta.city =ta2.city)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

"TA" is just an alias. It is **not** a variable. It simply lets you refer to the table with shorthand so that your queries are clearer.

If you only want the duplicate values then you can do this more easily with an aggregate function and the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    TA.name,
    TA.age,
    TA.city
FROM
    MyTableName TA
GROUP BY
    TA.name,
    TA.age,
    TA.city
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I'm not sure why your original query is timing out (other than maybe your table is too large for that query to return in time), but I notice that you don't have a statement terminator (semicolon for PostgreSQL). I haven't worked with PostgreSQL in a few years, so I don't recall if that's required or not, but I would add it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  This will allow you to bring back all of the ID's as well rather than just the three columns that have multiple values.

```
SELECT x.* from mytablename x
INNER JOIN (
          SELECT concat(y.name,'|',y.age,'|',y.city) as 'Fields'
          FROM mytablename y
          GROUP BY concat(y.name,'|',y.age,'|',y.city)
          HAVING count(*) > 1
          ) y on concat(x.name,'|',x.age,'|',x.city) = y.Fields
```